# Query SQL uso count + distinct valores unicos

Tags: sql

Tengo este query:

```
 SELECT count(*) as total, * FROM ( select case when pd_edad <=0 then '01'
when pd_edad >=65 then '15' 
END as age_range,pd_sexo,pd_diagnostico from paciente
where PD_CFEC between '2017/01/12' and '2017/31/12') t
group by PD_SEXO,age_range,pd_diagnostico
order by PD_SEXO desc,age_range asc, pd_diagnostico asc
```

Tome de ejemplo, un modelo de aca para construir el query, 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito contar valores únicos del campo DNI que se encuentra en esta tabla, pero solo deseo visualizar solo estos campos por **rango de edades**, espero su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: con group by no necesitas el distinct por que alli lo agrupas por la clave que necesitas luego el campo que necesitas contar le haces un count, te estas explotando la cabeza por nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes incluir el modificador `DISTINCT` del [Count()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql), junto al atributo de la subconsulta por el cual quieres la asegurar unicidad del conteo.

La consulta seria asi:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT DNI) as total, PD_SEXO, age_range, pd_diagnostico
FROM ( 
Select DNI, 
CASE 
WHEN pd_edad >=0 and pd_edad <= 20 then '01'
WHEN pd_edad >=21 and pd_edad <= 32 then '02'
WHEN pd_edad >=33 and pd_edad <= 42 then '03'
WHEN pd_edad >=65 and pd_edad <= 100 then '15' 
   --O Tantos rangos como quieras
ELSE
pd_edad --Para los que no estan en los rangos
END as age_range,
pd_sexo,pd_diagnostico 
FROM paciente
WHERE PD_CFEC between '2017/01/12' and '2017/31/12') t
GROUP BY PD_SEXO,age_range,pd_diagnostico
ORDER BY PD_SEXO desc,age_range asc, pd_diagnostico asc
```

Pd: Esto suponiendo que tu motor de base de datos sea SQL-Server.

Comment: Gracias, por la respuesta acertada, la parte de la sub-consulta no entendía como implementarla, gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

proba agregarle dentro del count (distinct + CampoAver).

```
select count (distinct DNI) from zzz
```

Tambien tenes algo asi:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)FROM TABLA1 (SELECT DISTINCT DNI FROM TABLA);
GROUP BY ALGO
```

Comment: Hola, probé con lo sugerido así como también otras modificaciones, pero no realiza el objetivo en este query en especifico, me podrías ayudar a replantearlo de otra manera?, saludos.

Comment: Hola nuevamente, este fue mi primer query, si realizaba el conteo unico, pero lo que yo necesitaba es realizar conteo por rangos de edad (en grupos de edades), por ejemplo: <=0 ; 1 a 5 ; etc :SELECT count(distinct(pd_hcli)) as total,PD_SEXO,PD_DIAG,PD_EDAD
from adpadir
where PD_CFEC between '2017/01/12' and '2017/31/12' and PD_DIAG='i10.x' and PD_EDAD >=65
group by PD_SEXO,PD_DIAG,PD_EDAD
order by PD_SEXO desc, PD_DIAG asc

Comment: el objetivo es la cuenta de DNI's únicos (no deseo que se visualicen este campo) por cada rango de edad (ejem: <=1; 2-20, 21-32, etc) y que se visualice los 4 campos  (total, age_range, pd_sexo y pd_diag); donde usaría Distinct, en el query inicial?, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Perdón, no me queda claro, todavía. A ver si con esto te puedo ayudar (debajo consulta SQL)

```
select top 1(
    select COUNT(1)
    from adpadir where PD_EDAD =16
    ) AS igual16,
    (select count (1) as n
    from adpadir where PD_EDAD <=22
      ) AS igual22
 FROM adpadir
```

Comment: Deberías de mejorar tu pregunta para evitar votos negativos, si bien el código es como un segundo idioma para muchos, no todos hablamos en los mismos lenguajes de programación, así que si pudieras agregar alguna explicación mínima como para alguien que apenas empiezasería muy beneficioso. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Remito el query final:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT pd_hcli) as total, pd_sexo, age_range, pd_diag
FROM ( 
Select pd_hcli, 
CASE 
WHEN pd_edad <=0  then '01'
WHEN pd_edad between 1 and 4   then '02'
WHEN pd_edad between 5 and 9   then '03'
WHEN pd_edad between 10 and 14 then '04'
WHEN pd_edad between 15 and 19 then '05'
WHEN pd_edad between 20 and 24 then '06'
WHEN pd_edad between 25 and 29 then '07'
WHEN pd_edad between 30 and 34 then '08'
WHEN pd_edad between 35 and 39 then '09'
WHEN pd_edad between 40 and 44 then '10'
WHEN pd_edad between 45 and 49 then '11'
WHEN pd_edad between 50 and 54 then '12'
WHEN pd_edad between 55 and 59 then '13'
WHEN pd_edad between 60 and 64 then '14'
WHEN pd_edad >=65 then '15' 
ELSE pd_edad END as age_range,
pd_sexo,pd_diag 
FROM adpadir
WHERE PD_CFEC between '2017/01/12' and '2017/31/12') t
GROUP BY PD_SEXO,age_range,PD_DIAG
ORDER BY PD_SEXO desc,age_range asc, PD_DIAG asc
```

El resultado arroja, total de pacientes únicos (pd_hcli) encontrados por cada diagnostico(pd_diag), a su vez ordenados por sexo(pd_sexo) y rango de edad(pd_edad), gracias por su apoyo comunidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]